# Gradle - A problem occurred evaluating root project (Android)

Tags: android, repository, build.gradle

hello there I was trying to add this repository

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

but don't know why I'm getting this error (never happened before)

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Dog Howl'.
> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'
```

**full code**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in your projects `settings.gradle` add the repositories you want to

```
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
       repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
       jcenter()
       maven { url "https://maven.xyz.com" }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes all this  threes are there in the settings.gradle google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon